# Finding max value of a loop with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find max value of a loop. First, I have two random arrays and I want to find these two arrays correlation coefficient. Then, I want to calculate it multiple times as much as "I3" cell. After that, I want to write a code which finds max correlation coefficient from this calculation. I wrote the code below but it didn't work.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Range("I3")
    Calculate
Next

DMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max("A2")
Range("I4").Value = DMax

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `Range("I3")`, are you referring to value in this cell or...? And what you want to achieve by calling `Max` on a single cell? Maximum of one value returns that value...

Comment: Range("I3") refers to value in this cell. I want to calculate coefficient as much as this value. And I want to find max of these values with a code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Max-Function needs a proper argument. Just typing "A2" doesn't work in VBA. Try:

```
DMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A2"))
```

This will give you the max-Value of the Array *A2*. But keep in mind that the max-Value of a range consisting of a single cell is always the cell value.

---

If you want to calculate the maximum value of all iterations, you should use the max-function in each iteration (inside for-loop) and store it's value. In each following iteration you should then overwrite the max-Value if your new max value is larger than the old one. Just like this:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim i As Long
DMax = 0
For i = 1 To Range("I3")
    Calculate
    DMax2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(...))
    If DMax2 > DMax Then DMax = DMax2
Next i

Range("I4").Value = DMax
```

This will give you the max-Value of Range(...) of all iterations.

Comment: Yes and this is my problem. Do you have an idea about how can I fix it?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Now I understand, I should write "A2" for my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you just write *Range("A2")* as argument of max-Function you don't need the function as the maximum of a single value is the single value. Instead you can simply store that single value.

Comment: So you mean what should I write?

Comment: If you want to have the maximum value of *Range("A2")* of all iterations, you can simply store the value of that range and compary them in each iteration: `If Range("A2").Value > DMax Then DMax = Range("A2").Value` instead of the two lines after *Calculate*

Comment: I've done it that way but it doesn't give the maximum value.

Comment: Just to make sure I get that case right:
You are generating random values and calculate their correlation coefficient in Cell *A2*. You repeat this a number of times and you want to have as result the maximum correlation coefficient of all cycles. Right?

Answer (score 0):

I barely understand your code, but the solution will be nasted loop. Suppose you have two sets of numbers: `A2` (`Cells(2, 1)`) through `I2` (`Cells(2, 7)`)  and `A3` (`Cells(3, 1)`) through `I3` (`Cells(3, 7)`). You want to calculate partial correlation and find what was the maximum value of it.

```
For i = 1 To 7
    For j = 1 To i
        'Calculate the correlation
    Next j
    'here you have partial coefficient and you can compare it,
    'if it is greater than previous one then save it and store
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For i = 1 To Range("I3").value 'to calculate from 1 to the value in that cell
```

what i would recommend for your question.

```
For i = 1 To 10 ' loop 10 times
    For j = 1 To i ' here it will allow you to check your stuff multiple times before moving on to the next value
    arr1(i) = arr2(j) ' see if your array match
    Next j

Next i
```